# What else can I do to protect my accounts?

Tags: physical, account-security

I am trying to make sure all my accounts are secure from unauthorised access and have turned on all security measures that I can find to make sure my stuff is protected.

Here is what I have in place:

- Unique password for every site (takes 6 billion years to crack) using MasterPassword since it is offline, meaning it is harder to attack
- Enabled 2-step verification when available
- Enabled FileValt on my Mac
- Enabled face detection on my mac so it automatically locks when I am away from the screen or detects someone else is using my computer. To login, I need to blink to make sure someone hasn't printed out a picture of my face
- Enabled find my iPhone so I can remotely erase my data remotely
- I do not allow my browser to save usernames, passwords or credit cards
- AutoFill is disabled
- I have [haveibeenpwned](https://haveibeenpwned.com) to alert me when it finds a service I use has its database leaked

Is there anything else that I could add to protect my accounts and data? (This includes both physical attacks and remote attacks on my MacBook Pro 2015 as well as my Internet accounts)

Comment: These are all really good ideas (I question the face detection, but that's an opinion), but I'm not sure that this question is a good fit for this site. It is too open-ended. For instance, I could say that you do not mention whether or not you change all your passwords every 90 days, but that's not a definitive answer. It is also not limited to accounts, but physical security of your machine, which makes it too broad.

Comment: @schroeder So if I take out physical security, would less broad so therefor unlocked? Also with the face detection, I know it can be insecure, however I need to blink in order for it to log me in. Also when showing a phone screen up to the camera (say for a video of me blinking) it doesn't show up that good. Also it takes a pictures of the "highjacks" so I know who they are.

Comment: It would still be too broad, but in terms of possible answers. The idea here is that Questions could have a definitive Answer, instead of a typical forum that encourages discussion.

Comment: @schroeder Thanks. Would I be able to ask for ideas then? Or what's a better way in asking this?

Comment: @iProgram If you want to *discuss* this, you might want to give [chat] a try. The main site is specifically for questions that allow for a single, authoritative answer. See for example [How do I ask a good question?](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [help].